# Vagrant: Problem with vagrant ssh when sha-1 key is in .ssh/config for unrelated host

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I am using Vagrant to create hosts in network simulations. Recently, I re-installed an old pet-computer (ACME Foxboard, if you're interested) that still ran a very old Linux version. So old, that it required me to put

```
Host foxboard
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

in my `.ssh/config`, which is valid syntax from ssh version 7 on. However, since I did that, `vagrant ssh` started to refuse access to my machines:

```
$ vagrant ssh
/home/ljm/.ssh/config line 2: Bad SSH2 KexAlgorithms '+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'.
```

Now, Vagrant states on its website:

> > SSH client usage
> >
> > Vagrant will attempt to use the local SSH client installed on the host machine. On POSIX machines, an SSH client must be installed and available on the PATH.

So, I would expect things to work, especially because:

```
$ ssh -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:
```

seems to work. But that means I have to distribute keys to all my machines to log-in.

Also, during boot, Vagrant seems to be able to ssh into the machine and, for example, change the ssh-keys.

Is there a solution that allows me to ssh into my personal computer museum and use a simple `vagrant ssh`?